# why my php script always error on undefined index

Tags: php, undefined-index

I make search function in one php file. but after i separate them my coding show undefined index. Any can help me to solve this error the undefine index for the full_name not string

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (file_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')";
}

if ($_REQUEST["file_name"]<>''){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE file_name'".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["file_name"])."'".$search_string;
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE file_id>0 ".$search_string;
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id=$row['file_id']?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["file_id"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["file_reference"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["file_name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["file_location"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["file_pdf"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

any suggestion to solve undefined error on my coding.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use `isset` to check, if variable or key exists.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['string']) && $_REQUEST["string"] != '') {
    // $_REQUEST['string'] exists and is non-empty
}
```

For others it will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you check to see if `$_REQUEST["string"]<>''` you are actually trying to access that index. use `isset()` to check that it is set first.

Also, what line are you getting the error on, because it could also be that you are trying to access a column that isn't in your query response.  So there could be multiple places where you'd get that error in this code.

Comment: undefine index on file_name

Comment: that's probably near the top, you should check to see `if(isset($_REQUEST["file_name"]))` before you try to use it in your query.  You're doing some check on `full_name` and then using `file_name` before ever checking that it exists

Comment: so I see that you updated the question and changed `full_name` to `file_name`.  Maybe the `isset()` check seems unnecessary to you at this point, but trust me you won't be done with this fix until you check that.